# Can't make complex SQL request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

I have two separate models **MarketOrder** and **OnlineOrder**.

Two models **do not have** any relationship between them but need to be displayed in one table.

Sorting and Pagination required. Simple solution would be:

```
orders = (MarketOrder.all + OnlineOrder.all).sort_by(&:created_at).paginate(per_page: 50, page: params[:page])
```

This works fine but it is not suitable as number of orders constantly grows. Query all records would cause a huge drop in performance. How correctly to narrow such query? Thanks

*Update*

Models do not have exactly the same columns but share some common ones which need to be displayed in my view file.

```
MarketOrder(
  id: integer, 
  user_id: integer, 
  service_fee_amount: decimal, 
  status: string, price: decimal, 
  created_at: datetime, 
  updated_at: datetime..
)
```

```
OnlineOrder(
  id: integer, 
  user_id: integer, 
  category: string, 
  comment: text, 
  status: string, 
  price: decimal, 
  created_at: datetime, 
  updated_at: datetime...
)
```

Please note that both models are independent and Ids in both go 1,2,3... 1,2,3...

But each model has a relation with a third model User (belongs_to <=> has_many) and where each table contains user_id.

as per `sort_by(&:created_at).paginate(per_page: 50, page: params[:page])` 50 most recent orders would be prepared with jbuilder and send to react component. To get next 50 orders the request would be made again to backend.

Comment: Please update with the db tables structure.

Comment: These two models of yours share the same attributes?

Comment: What the above users are looking for is a way to help you create a "UNION". The Schema will be important to this but can you also tell us specifically what columns (`methods`) you are using in your view?

Comment: Calling `.all` on two different models and then smashing the results together is going to get *very* expensive if those tables grow to a non-trivial size.

Comment: you're right. that is what I am looking for, some optimisation

Comment: Not quite the question you’re asking, but if you can write the SQL you want, it might make sense to put it in a database view and then wrap a read-only view around it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a polymorphic table Order, should have fields `order_link_type` (string), `order_link_id` (integer) and `order_created_at` (datetime)

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order_link, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end

class MarketOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :order, as: :order_link, dependent: :destroy
  after_save :create_order
  private
  def create_order
    return if order

    build_order(order_created_at: created_at)
  end
end


class OnlineOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :order, as: :order_link, dependent: :destroy
  after_save :create_order
  private
  def create_order
    return if order

    build_order(order_created_at: created_at)
  end
end
```

and now you can do...

```
orders = Order.all.sort_by(&:order_created_at).paginate(per_page: 50, page: params[:page])
```

You can access the fields in your view as `order.order_link.user_id` and for the fields that only exist on one type or order link you can conditionally retrieve the value, like `order.order_link.try(:comment)`  You may want to `delegate` to the `Order` class some of the fields so you can just reference `order.user_id`